# Let $X∼N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y∼N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ be two independent normal variables. find $x$ so $\Phi(x)=P(X_1<4X_2)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Let $X\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ be two independent normal variables. calculate $x$ so $\Phi(x)=P(X_1<4X_2)$.
I know that this question should be solved by standardizing a new variable $X_1-4X_2$ but it isn't giving me any progress because I always get to an integration that I don't know to calculate.
Any help?

Comment: No integrals are needed. $X_1-4X_2$ is a normal random variable (why?). What is the mean and variance?

Comment: 1−42 ∼ (1 - 42,1^2 - 42^2)
right?

Comment: The mean is correct; the variance is not. If $\sigma_1=1$ and $\sigma_2=2$, your formula implies the variance is negative! If $X$ and $Y$ are any **independent** RVs, try to find a general formula for $\operatorname{Var}(aX+bY)$ starting from the definitions.

Comment: So the variance is (1 + 162)^(1/2)? what to do after this?

Comment: Statement seems to be missing something. Where is x on the r.h.s.?  It looks like $\Phi=P(4X_2-X_1\gt 0)$ which is a number.